# Django - How to process JSON response from TwelveData API in Template?

Tags: python, django, twelvedata

In a hobby project, I am using TwelveData API to receive Time Series Data. I am using JSON format response and able to check each data (example: open, close, high, and etc.) from Python side, but the problem arises when I try to show the data in a Django Template page using a for-loop. The JSON response is similar to below image:

[image]

When I write the following for loop in the template:

```
{%for r in result %}
    {{r}}
{%endfor %}
```

It  prints GOOGL, AAPL, AMZN, and TSLA <-- which is pretty good. Now when I write another for loop like:

```
{%for r in result %}
    {%for k in result.r %}
        {{k}}
    {%endfor %}
{%endfor %}
```

It prints nothing except a blank page. So I rewrite the main for-loop as follows:

```
{%for r,v in result %}
    {{v}}
{%endfor %}
```

It prints **ValueError: Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 5.**

Can anyone help me identify how to run the loop accurately so that I can get/print (maybe inside a table  tag) the JSON response data as follows: open, close, high, and etc.

- Thanks

Comment: Please post your data as text. Screenshots of text are far less helpful than the text itself.

Comment: Here is the data as text: https://notepad.pw/i10y8247

Comment: Why don't just add it to the question itself, as it is expected on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use items for result

```
{% for r,v in result.items %}
    {{r}} - {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also you need to convert string to json

```
import json

# somewhere before you pass result to template
result = json.loads(result)
```

Comment: No, it returns: ValueError: Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 5

Comment: plese provide test data, and all template

Comment: Here is the test data: https://notepad.pw/i10y8247

I just pass result from the backend, which produces an exact output of the file when type ```{{ result }}```

Comment: it seems I got it, you need to convert string to json

Comment: if it does not work, please provide code how you pass result to template. in this case this is very important

Answer (score 0):

Using `result.r` will make Django look for property, not value of the key. That is why its print nothing using your second code. You could see [Anton Pomieshchenko's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65558992/14935880) to enumerate a dict or write a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) if you want to get the value of a specific key:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

usage:

```
{% for r in result %}
    {{ result|get_item:r }}
{% endfor %}
```